# How to use Headless task to fetch data every 15 seconds when app is in background?

Tags: java, android, react-native

I need for my application to perform every 15 seconds a request to the server, only when the app is in background.
I can't seem to find any tutorial explaining how to use headless tasks to do a complete task with all examples. For now I just tried to do the following.

```
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('PracticeTask', () => async (data) => {
    const { dispatch, getState } = data;
    console.log(dispatch, getState);

    return true;
});

AppState.addEventListener('change', nextAppState => {
    if(nextAppState === "background"){
        AppRegistry.startHeadlessTask(1, 'PracticeTask', { dispatch: store.dispatch, getState: store.getState });
    }
});
```

My Java file looks like this :

package com.project;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.facebook.react.HeadlessJsTaskService;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
import com.facebook.react.jstasks.HeadlessJsTaskConfig;

public class PracticeTaskService extends HeadlessJsTaskService {
    @Override
    protected HeadlessJsTaskConfig getTaskConfig(Intent intent){
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if(extras != null){
            return new HeadlessJsTaskConfig(
                "PracticeTask",
                Arguments.fromBundle(extras),
                50
            );
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

When the app goes in background, it just crashes. But the console.log is made.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **[AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)** API. Specifically checkout **[Scheduling repeated Alarms](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)**.

**Simple example-**

```
public void startAlarm(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SyncService.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                10 min, 20 min, sender);

}
```

**(From [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html))
Note:** Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, PendingIntent). Applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when requested.

Use the new **[JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) API**(older *(Lollipop--)* equivalent of the same is [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html))

**Ensure you register it via your Android manifest.**

**Simple Example-**

```
/**
 * JobService to be scheduled by the JobScheduler.
 * Requests scheduled with the JobScheduler call the "onStartJob" method
 */
public class TestJobService extends JobService {
        private static final String TAG = "SyncService";

        @Override
        public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
                // fake work
                Log.i(TAG, "on start job: " + params.getJobId());
                return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
                return true;
        }

}
```

Comment: My app supports API 16+ so JobScheduler wont do. AlarmManager seems to work only for long period. I've found some kind of workaround but it requires calling a Callback multiple times, but React docs says it's not possible to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I found this https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer
This solves the hell out of the problem.

Comment: Superb.. I just able to achieve my requirement with this